# How to store and call multiple stylesheets with php?

Tags: php

I'm trying to store multiple stylesheets in a .php file and I want to call these files by url:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.php?stylesheet1'>
```

and on another page that should be styled differently:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.php?stylesheet2'>
```

I'm currently using an array to compile multiple stylesheets and then using a script I found to minify them

```
$cssFiles = array(
"templates/css/part1.css",
"templates/css/part2.css"
);
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: How can I store 2 stylesheets and then call them via url (style.php?stylesheet1 and style.php?stylesheet2)?

Comment: What does your array and the minifying have to do with that? What are the files called? Most importantly, what have you tried?

Comment: I'm confused on how to do it. I tried assigning variables to the stylesheets but have no idea how to call them via url since I'm unfamiliar with php

Comment: You need to provide more information (the information I just described). You can use [the "edit" link under your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33725325/edit) to do that. Without that, we don't even know what you want, and your question is too broad. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you could just store 2 strings in style.php, and serve the correct one based on the parameter passed

Comment: I want to store 2 stylesheets in a .php file called style.php. I then want to call those 2 stylesheets via url. So when I call style.php?style1.css it comes back with the first stylesheet and style.php?style2.css comes back with the second. I don't know how to make this any clearer sorry

Comment: i don't see the point at all, may as well call the css directly. But `file_get_contents()`, and don't forget the correct headers, is one approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try something like this

**index.html**

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.php?style=1'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.php?style=2'>
```

**style.php**

```
<?php
$cssFiles = array(
"/templates/css/part1.css",
"/templates/css/part2.css"
);


$file = (isset( $_GET['style'] ) && is_numeric($_GET['style'])) ? intval($_GET['style'] ) : '';

if(!empty($file) && isset($cssFiles[$file - 1]))
    $file = $cssFiles[$file - 1];
    else
    $file = $cssFiles[0];

if(file_exists($file))
    include $file;

    ?>
```

Comment: dont forget the headers

Comment: i'm not here to do all the work, this is just a guide.. plus this will work without headers...